# How to understand whether it is $ or jQuery OR custom names like ravi('p').html, somename('.class')?

Tags: jquery

Generally we can use `$` symbol or `jQuery` name or any other name... so how does the jQuery library find out whether it is `$` symbol or `jQuery` or custom name?

Comment: Look at the initialization code for `noConflict()` calls?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't care what global variable(s) it is assigned to.

If you look at the [source code](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js) you can see that the entirety of jQuery is defined inside IIFEs.

When jQuery needs to access itself, it does so through *local* variables in those functions.